# NO. DIFFICULTY. PUZZLE

Tags: lateral-thinking

Up here is down on the ________ side.
The article used in this sentence.
What is this again?
The verb used above
The second answer is here too.
Open my lock with a ___.

Where is the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so... taking them one line at a time...
>  Opposite The Puzzle Is The Key

> ...which suggests that the key is "NO"... or perhaps that there is no key.

Comment: Almost… your interpretation of the first one is not correct. Think of the globe

Comment: @Someone edited.  Better?

Comment: rot13( Hc urer vf qbja ba gur bgure urzvfcurer fvqr? 'Bgure urzvfcurer gur chmmyr vf gur xrl' )... Also I don't understand the line "The answer is here too".

Comment: @Stef that looks more like an comment on the question than a comment on my answer.

Comment: @BenBarden The op just commented that your interpretation of the first one wasn't correct. I suggested another interpretation of the first one, although as-is it doesn't explain where the key is.

Comment: The first word might be rot13(haqre)?

Comment: @Mohirl that was my first response, which drew the initial comment from OP.  I've responded by editing my answer and the OP hasn't yet responded to that edit.

Comment: Opposite the puzzle is the key... perhaps Antipode?

Comment: Once you get there, you find a boat with a key. But what does it open?

Comment: @Someone that sounds like a follow-on puzzle that should perhaps be posted as its own question.

Comment: I'm thinking of adding the link here once it's finished.

Comment: [Here it is](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102110/found-the-key-but-what-to-unlock)