# Found the key, but what to unlock?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Here's a series of text messages between me and my friend.

Me: Couldn't use ebg13, so used ______ to hide my messages.
Him: What? How is this possible???
Me: A big prime ______, what else did you expect?
Him: Hmm.
Me:(Note: this is multiline. Also, this is not part of the text. See below.)

```
    ˄
    N
˂ E ? W ˃
    S
    ˅
```

.________ ƨɒw ɈxɘɈ ƨiʜɈ ƨƨɘυϱ I
Him: You have a secret message! But… it's just incoherent words.
Me: A padlock *and* a word lock? Oh my!
Him: More encryptions, huh?
Me: yep. bsixfour,spoilthirteen,atcommandlanguage.

What *is* the code?

## HINT

> that last text contains the name of three encryptions. Split them up!

## HIINT

> Only look at my texts. His are just replies.

## HIIINT

> the first of the last is the answer of the first.

## HIVNT

> I accidentally flopped the ____ and ____.

## HVNT

> As with all my puzzles, what goes in the underscores is the same length as the number of underscores.